# SQL Query to eliminate similar entries

Tags: sql, algorithm, duplicates, combinations

I am working on a problem in SQL Server 2008

I have a table with six columns:

```
PK INT
dOne SmallINT
dTwo SmallINT
dThree SmallINT
dFour SmallINT
dFiveSmallINT
dSix SmallINT
```

The table contains around a million recrods. It's probably worth noting that value in column n+1 > value in column n i.e. 97, 98, 99, 120, 135. I am trying to eliminate all rows which have 5 DIGITS in common (ignoring the PK) i.e.:

```
76, 89, 99, 102, 155, 122
11, 89, 99, 102, 155, 122
89, 99, 102, 155, 122, 130
```

In this case the algorithm should start at the first row and delete the second and third rows because they contain 5 matching digits. The first row persists.

I have tried to brute force the solution but finding all the duplicates for only the first record takes upwards of 25 seconds meaning processing the whole table would take... way too long (this should be a repeatable process).

I am fairly new to SQL but this is what I have come up with (I have come up with a few solutions but none were adequate... this is the latest attempt):

(I won't include all the code but I will explain the method, I can paste more if it helps)

Save the digits of record n into variables. SELECT all records which have one digit in common with record n FROM largeTable.

Insert all selected digits into #oneMatch and include [matchingOne] with the digit that matched.

Select all records which have one digit in common with record n FROM the temp table WHERE 'digit in common' != [matching]. INSERT all selected digits into #twoMatch and include [matchingOne] AND [matchingTwo]...

Repeat until inserting into #fiveMatch. Delete #fiveMatch from largeTable and move to record n+1

I am having a problem implementing this solution. How can I assign the matching variable depending on the WHERE clause?

```
-- SELECT all records with ONE matching field:
INSERT INTO #oneMatch (ID_pk, dOne, dTwo, dThree, dFour, dFive, dSix, mOne)
SELECT ID_pk, dOne, dTwo, dThree, dFour, dFive, dSix
FROM dbo.BaseCombinationsExtended
WHERE  ( [dOne] IN (@dOne, @dTwo, @dThree, @dFour, @dFive, @dSix) **mOne = dOne?
      OR [dTwo] IN (@dOne, @dTwo, @dThree, @dFour, @dFive, @dSix) **mOne = dTwo?
      OR [dTwo] IN (@dOne, @dTwo, @dThree, @dFour, @dFive, @dSix) **mOne = dThree?
...
      OR [dSix] IN (@dOne, @dTwo, @dThree, @dFour, @dFive, @dSix) **mOne = dSix?
    )
```

I am able to 'fake' the above using six queries but that is too inefficient...

Sorry for the long description. Any help would be greatly appreciated (new solution or implementation of my attempt above) as this problem has been nagging at me for a while...

Comment: This is a good case  for normalization.

Comment: Could you please elaborate for me? (RDB are not my strongest suit so forgive my ignorance) How can I normalize when there is only one table and no relationships?

Comment: There must be a relationship if you are comparing the fields on the same row to each other.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. There should be multiple tables (or at least two) with relationships.

Comment: Or even one table with a composite PK

Comment: When you say "delete the second and third rows", what makes you choose these? Lowest PK value? And what if other rows match 5 different values for, say, the 2nd row? Then what?

Comment: Seems like you could end up deleting quite a few rows as one row could match different rows in different ways.  Are you sure of what you want here?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I miss something this should produce the correct result.

```
declare @T table 
(
  PK INT identity primary key,
  dOne SmallINT,
  dTwo SmallINT,
  dThree SmallINT,
  dFour SmallINT,
  dFive SmallINT,
  dSix SmallINT
)

insert into @T values
(76, 89, 99, 102, 155, 122),
(11, 89, 99, 102, 155, 122),
(89, 99, 102, 155, 122, 130)

;with q1(PK, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) as
(
  select PK, dTwo, dThree, dFour, dFive, dSix
  from @T
  union all
  select PK, dOne, dThree, dFour, dFive, dSix
  from @T
  union all
  select PK, dOne, dTwo, dFour, dFive, dSix
  from @T
  union all
  select PK, dOne, dTwo, dThree, dFive, dSix
  from @T
  union all
  select PK, dOne, dTwo, dThree, dFour, dSix
  from @T
  union all
  select PK, dOne, dTwo, dThree, dFour, dFive
  from @T
),
q2 as
(
  select PK,
         row_number() over(partition by d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 order by PK) as rn
  from q1
),
q3 as
(
  select PK
  from q2
  where rn = 1
  group by PK
  having count(*) = 6   
)
select T.*
from @T as T
  inner join q3 as Q
    on T.PK = Q.PK
```

Comment: You solved it.  Converted to a mere O(n log n) problem.  I didn't see it.  Good job.

Comment: @user - Thanks. It uses the fact that the values are ordered with increasing values in the columns left to right. But I'm not sure this is the algorithm OP actually wants. This will "cascade" the deletes. With three rows like this (1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,7),(1,2,3,4,7,8) only row 1 will be kept but if we first remove all matches against row 1 and then for row 2 etc... both row 1 and row 3 will remain. If that is desired I'm afraid we are back to O(N^2) again.

Comment: Good point about the cascading deletes.  That's what I was trying to ask about in the last comment I made on the question.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I'm just finishing at this job and it's been hectic. This solution is excellent but unfortunately I do need to perform 'sequential' deletions. I think we have got it based on some earlier advice and suggestions... By partitioning the table into clumps of 25K and processing the first 10K of each partition performance drastically improved (11K deletes in 90 minutes with only one set running). Once every group of 25K is processed, repeat the process with new groups of 25K. Finally, we do one run over the remaining records (<200K) to ensure we catch all the outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - the following approach *might* be better than N squared performance, depending on the optimizer.  If all 5 columns are indexed it should only need 6 index seeks per row, which is still N * logN.  It does seem a little dopey though.

You could code generate the where condition based on all the permutations of 5 matches:  so the records to delete would be given by:

```
SELECT * FROM SillyTable ToDelete WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT PK From SillyTable Duplicate 
    WHERE (   (
            (Duplicate.dOne=ToDelete.dOne) 
            AND (Duplicate.dTwo=ToDelete.dTwo) 
            AND (Duplicate.dThree=ToDelete.dThree)
            AND (Duplicate.dFour=ToDelete.dFour)
            AND (Duplicate.dFive=ToDelete.dFive)
        ) OR (
            (Duplicate.dOne=ToDelete.dTwo) 
            AND (Duplicate.dTwo=ToDelete.dThree) 
            AND (Duplicate.dThree=ToDelete.dFour)
            AND (Duplicate.dFour=ToDelete.dFive)
            AND (Duplicate.dFive=ToDelete.dSix)
        ) OR (
            (Duplicate.dTwo=ToDelete.dOne) 
            AND (Duplicate.dThree=ToDelete.dTwo) 
            AND (Duplicate.dFour=ToDelete.dThree)
            AND (Duplicate.dFive=ToDelete.dFour)
            AND (Duplicate.dSix=ToDelete.dFive)
        ) OR (
            (Duplicate.dTwo=ToDelete.dTwo) 
            AND (Duplicate.dThree=ToDelete.dThree) 
            AND (Duplicate.dFour=ToDelete.dFour)
            AND (Duplicate.dFive=ToDelete.dFive)
            AND (Duplicate.dSix=ToDelete.dSix)
        ) ...
```

This goes on to cover all 36 combinations (there is one non-match on each side of the join, out of 6 possible columns, so 6*6 gives you all the possibilites).  I would code generate this because it's a lot of typing, and what if you want 4 out of 6 matches tomorrow, but you could hand code it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any promises on performance, but you can try this. The first thing that I do is put the data into a more normalized structure.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized (my_id INT NOT NULL, c SMALLINT NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized (my_id, c)
SELECT my_id, c1 FROM dbo.Test_Sets UNION ALL
SELECT my_id, c2 FROM dbo.Test_Sets UNION ALL
SELECT my_id, c3 FROM dbo.Test_Sets UNION ALL
SELECT my_id, c4 FROM dbo.Test_Sets UNION ALL
SELECT my_id, c5 FROM dbo.Test_Sets UNION ALL
SELECT my_id, c6 FROM dbo.Test_Sets
GO

SELECT DISTINCT
    T2.my_id
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT my_id FROM dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized) T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT my_id FROM dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized) T2 ON T2.my_id > T1.my_id
WHERE
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized T3
    INNER JOIN dbo.Test_Sets_Normalized T4 ON
        T4.my_id = T2.my_id AND
        T4.c = T3.c
    WHERE
        T3.my_id = T1.my_id) >= 5
```

That should get you the IDs that you need. Once you've confirmed that it does what you want, you can `JOIN` back to the original table and delete by IDs.

There's probably an improvement possible somewhere that doesn't require the `DISTINCT`. I'll give it a little more thought.

Comment: You could get my_id from dbo.Test_Sets without requiring DISTINCT

Comment: Thanks Tom and psr for your suggestions. Sorry, I can't implement them right away (at work) but as soon as I have a free moment I will give them a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: I've been playing with similar ideas and I think I can make a promise that performance will be absolutely atrocious.

Comment: @gbn - True. I wanted to show it fully with the new table though in case he's able to normalize the database down the road.